# Launch Java Web Start Application from HTTPS urls

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, java-web-start, jnlp

My web application is developed in 
**PHP** that launch a java web start application. My jar is signed by the trusted certificate authority. It was working fine with **No SSL** web application. But now site has been configured with trusted SSL certificate.So now I am not able to launch my plugin.

I am getting this exception while launching the application.

> **Exception thrown :**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My JNLP file is as below :

> **JNLP File :**

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="https://<<server_domain>>/MyPlugin/">
  <information>
    <title>Test Plugin</title>
    <vendor>Test</vendor>
    <description>Test Plugin</description>
    <description kind="short">Test Plugin</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <update check="timeout" policy="always"/>
  <resources>
    <java version="1.7+"/>
    <jar href="MyPluginJar.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
  </resources>
  <application-desc>
    <argument>test</argument>
    <argument>test</argument>
  </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

> **Few Questions :**

1. Is it possible to launch java web start from **HTTPS** site ?
2. I have gone through the demos provided by the Oracle ("[tutorial site](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/)"). Tutorial site is HTTPS site but the **codebase in JNLP file contains HTTP urls**. Does it matter of concern ?
3. Is there anything wrong in my JNLP ?
4. Is there a way to allow this particular request in SSL configuration to serve ? (Server using for PHP site : **apache web server**)
5. Any other work around for the achieving this ?

Please help on this.

**UPDATE :**

I got the solution.

**Solution :**

The 2nd question ( **I have gone through the demos provided by the Oracle ("[tutorial site](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/)"). Tutorial site is HTTPS site but the **codebase in JNLP file contains HTTP urls**. Does it matter of concern ?**) I have asked was the **Really matter of concern**.

I have deployed another application in the server with **no SSL configuration**. And I call that in the code-base to launch the java plugin.

**Still, I didn't get the cause. But yes this is perfect work around for the exception.**

Comment: I have the same issue. What worked for you?

Comment: have updated solution already..